# Non-matching rows between two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, difference

I am new to Python and would like to seek you help on this please.
I would like to find out the non-matching rows between 2 dataframes i.e. df1 and df2 with thousands of rows. They both contain the same number of columns with the same name.

df2 has 10 entries lesser than df1 which I am trying to find out what they are.
I have tried `pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)` but it returns zero result.

What could be the reason?
Any help/advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're trying to find the *difference* between the two frames. `contact` on the other hand *combines* two frames. You can use [compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) for this

Answer (score 0):

The following code will remove rows in `df1` that are present in `df2`

```
df1[~df1.isin(df2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`concat` combines two frames. You're trying to find the difference between two frames. This can be done with [compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html). As the doc example shows, given these two frames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"],
        "col2": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, np.nan, 5.0],
        "col3": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
    },
    columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"],
)

df2 = df.copy()
df2.loc[0, 'col1'] = 'c'
df2.loc[2, 'col3'] = 4.0
```

You can find the different rows with `compare` :

```
df.compare(df2)
  col1       col3
  self other self other
0    a     c  NaN   NaN
2  NaN   NaN  3.0   4.0
```

In this case `compare` returns one row for every row that has a difference and only the columns that are actually different.

`compare` can return the equal values or all original values as well:

```
df.compare(df2, keep_equal=True)
  col1       col3
  self other self other
0    a     c  1.0   1.0
2    b     b  3.0   4.0
```

or

```
df.compare(df2, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)
  col1       col2       col3
  self other self other self other
0    a     c  1.0   1.0  1.0   1.0
1    a     a  2.0   2.0  2.0   2.0
2    b     b  3.0   3.0  3.0   4.0
3    b     b  NaN   NaN  4.0   4.0
4    a     a  5.0   5.0  5.0   5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have 10 less entries doesn't mean you're going to find duplicates. You probably already have duplicates inside the first dataframe.

Demo:

```
# Length: 7
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('AAABCDE'),
                    'col2': list('FFFGHIJ'),
                    'col3': list('1112345')})

# Length: 5
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('ABCDE'),
                    'col2': list('FGHIJ'),
                    'col3': list('12345')})
```

Your code:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, col3]
Index: []
```

Try:

```
>>> len(df1.drop_duplicates())
5

>>> len(df2.drop_duplicates())
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both df1 and df2 are Pandas Dataframe, the following code returns True for matching rows and false for the other:

```
print((df1 == df2).any(1))
```

If needed to check each and every columns in all the rows, try this:

```
print((df1 == df2).stack())
```

Comment: No, your code raises a `ValueError` exception because *Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects*. Try with my sample if you want to check.